# Room Android Error : The connection pool for database

Tags: android, android-room

The connection pool for database '+data+user+0+com_retailistan_salesflo+databases+sf_db_db' has been unable to grant a connection to thread 15791 (arch_disk_io_2) with flags 0x1 for 8.0060005 seconds.
Connections: 4 active, 0 idle, 0 available.

```
 fun getInstance(mCtx: Context): DatabaseClient? {

        return mInstance ?: synchronized(this) {
          val instance = DatabaseClient(mCtx)
            mInstance = instance
            Log.d("DatabaseClient", "getInstance calledt")
          // return instance
          instance
      }
```

init {

```
    appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(mCtx.applicationContext,
            AppDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME_ROOM)
            .addCallback(rdc)
            .build()

}
```

getInstance(this)!!.appDatabase

Comment: Can anyone knows why this error occur

Comment: Looks like you have 4 not closed connection to your db and the db can't create one more. Try to use one shared instance of connection to your db.

Comment: see the code i am using only shared instance only created by once

Comment: I hope your `mInstance` is volatile.  Can you reproduce this bug stably ? You can try to use fixed size threadpool for woking with DB.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using multiple connections (instance of the Room Database). Using a singleton (a single shared connection) would probably resolve the issue.

So instead of using something along the lines of :-

```
TheDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(this,TheDatabase.class,"mydatabase").build();
```

Along with TheDatabase being something like :-

```
@Database(entities = {State.class,Location.class,School.class,TimerDesign.class,IntervalDesign.class,Table1.class},exportSchema = false,version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract AllDao getAllDao();
}
```

Throughout the App. You could consider using :-

```
@Database(entities = {MyTableEntity.class},exportSchema = false,version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract AllDao getAllDao();
    
    private static volatile TheDatabase instance;
    public static TheDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context,
                    TheDatabase.class,
                    "mydatabase"
            ).build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

along with

```
db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this);
```

So you get the single connection throughout the App, instead of an additional connection.

Comment: see the code i am using only one instance same as you.

Comment: Your singleton is wrong! Your getInstance  should be synchronized or use something like  Double-Checked Locking. Please see paragraph Fixing Double-Checked Locking using Volatile (https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html )

Comment: My Room db instance is a dagger Singleton.   I'm seeing the same thing.   I would imagine dagger figured out how to inject a singleton properly.   I suspect something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility.  Perhaps your doing a very expensive operation in a transaction.  Let's say, inserting 1.8M records in transaction.

I'm using Dagger to inject the room db instance,  Room is opening and closing things internally. So I was pretty sure of none the previous answers addressed my issue.  I saw the message a bunch during a test case.  The message was always about the same table, so I started the logging the transactions to the table, when I discovered all the trouble started after trying to insert 1.8M records in a transaction.   I chunked the inserts in chucks of 10k items and the problem went away.